# What does the 'pyramid-height' field produce in the SPP Layer of caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

In the Spatial Pyramid Pooling layer of Caffe, there is a `pyramid_height` field to fill in your prototxt.

I see a lot of people referring to the combination of `1, 2, 3, 6` ([Another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102008/how-to-use-the-spatial-pyramid-layer-in-caffe-in-proto-files/45105910#45105910)) which is used in [the original SPPNet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729.pdf), but I can't tell for certain that it is that from looking at the open source code. Maybe it is `1, 2, 3, 4`?

Even if it is the one that people suggest, how does this scale? Is there a formula for figuring out what set of values my `pyramid_height` field will produce?